# InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

I have a custom class "Person" with properties such as Name, Email, etc. I have a List called "people", and I have a listView that displays the name of each item in the "people" list.

I'm trying to remove the "people" item that the user has selected in the listView, with the following line of code in a button1.Click event:

```
people.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
```

But it's throwing the error in the title, however, the code right after that removes the name from the listView it works with no problem:

```
listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

I was following the tutorial videos found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZoDmeAZAD8

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `.SelectedIndex` directly?

Comment: Please do not put links in your question.. if you can take the time to write the question, then you can obviously post the code that pertains to the issue that you are having

Comment: I put everything needed to answer the question within the question, I just also added a link to the code if anyone would like to see it. Please ask specific questions and I will get anything you need to know from the code and post it myself, thanks.

Comment: @ja72 listView1 doesn't have a SelectedIndex method, or were you referring to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was I removed it from listView1 before I removed it from List, so it couldn't find what I was referring to and threw an error.

So all I had to do was switch these two (already switched)

```
people.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index); // removes item from people LIST.
listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]); // removes item/person from LISTVIEW
```

and it works! Thank you everyone, and next time I will not post all the code in a separate link, sorry.

Comment: I do not recommend keeping two separate lists, one of `Person` and one of `ListViewItem`, and trying to synchronize them all the time. I recommend to act on the person list and the re-populate the listview from the `List<Person>`. Also I often link the `.Tag` property of `ListViewItem` with the class it represents, and then I can use the `IndexOf()` method of the list to find which index I must act on.